# Titanium using JSON Parsing

Tags: json, titanium

I am trying to retrieve data from PHPMyAdmin and trying to display the data to the picker change....
Here is my code
     var currentWin = Ti.UI.currentWindow;

```
 var sendit = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
 sendit.open('GET', 'http://localhost/mobileapp/productread.php');
 sendit.send();
  sendit.onload = function(){
 var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

 var json = json.mobile_product;

 var picker = Ti.UI.createPicker();
  // turn on the selection indicator (off by default)
 picker.selectionIndicator = true;

 var data = [];
  var pos;
 data.push (Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title:''+ json[pos].product_name +      '',custom_item:'b'}));
 }
 picker.add(data);
 currentWin.add(picker);



//var rw = db.execute("SELECT product_name, SUM(product_quantity)FROM mobile_product   GROUP BY product_name");

picker.addEventListener('change', function(e){
 var sendit = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
sendit.open('GET', 'http://localhost/mobileapp/orderread.php');
sendit.send();


sendit.onload = function(){
var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

var json = json.mobile_product;
 var pos;
var product_name = json[e.rowIndex];
 for (pos=0; pos < json.length; pos++) {

alert(''+json[pos].orders + '');
}
}
})
 }
```

Here when i change the picker, alert appears with all the values of the column(orders) for a single change... If I change the picker to the next, again the alert appears for all the datas in the column.. For example, If i have 10 values in the column(order), and if I change the picker valus, the alert appears 10 times with 10 values..
I want to display the value from the column according to the change in the picker....
I have retrieved data(product_name) from PHPMyAdmin for the picker... When I change the picker, i want the values for that particular names to be displayed....
I am using the Query
SELECT SUM(product_quantity) As orders FROM mobile_product GROUP BY product_name
in the PHP file..
My PHP file is

```
<?php
//cust-mysql-123-04
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
 if (!$link) {
die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}
// make foo the current db
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('mobileapp', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
die ('Can\'t use  : ' . mysql_error());
}
// Set the default namespace to utf8
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
if($result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(product_quantity) As orders FROM mobile_product     GROUP BY product_name")) {
//echo mysql_num_rows($result);
  while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   // $json.= "<li>".$row['first_name']."</li>";
    $json[]=array(
    'orders'=>$row['orders']
    );
 }
}
echo json_encode(array( 'mobile_product'  =>   $json ));

mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Can some one help me out on this???

Answer (score 0):

You will have to include a different value for use in the SQL query. Currently, it seems that there is only an aggregate function SUM(), a static GROUP statement and that is all. This will always return the same value.

You are also returning a different column set then you probably expect using the as orders alius.

If you are looking to return a different set, you will need to assemble a different SQL SELECT statement.

Consider the following documents:

1. [This is how to prepare and execute a SQL statement against MySQL in
   php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)
2. [This function will clear many issues from the variable you
   pass to it](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)
3. [Finally, you build the request with this method in
   Titanium.](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient)
4. [You may wish to review the following document regarding forming and
   consuming a GET request, as well](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp)